# Error While connecting SQL server through VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba

I am trying to insert data from vba to sql server but its throwing up an error please help me.

[image]

```
Excel_SQL()

Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
con.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=ev01LAP130\MSSQLSERVER1;Database:=Sample 1,Uid=Meera;Password=meeraagrawal"

Dim slry As Variant

Dim my_table, Data As Range
Set my_table = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    
For Each Data In my_table.Rows
     Name = Data.Cells(2, 1).Value
     slry = Data.Cells(2, 2).Value
     Sql = "insert into emp values('" & Name & "'," & slry & ")"
    '         MsgBox Sql
     con.Execute Sql  
Next Data
con.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: It seems the table name is faulty. Can you test your insert statement in SSMS? Does the database have schemas that might prevent finding the emp table?

Comment: You need a semikolon between Database and UID

Comment: Also, remove the colon after the Database leyword. The connection string should be `"Driver={SQL Server};Server=ev01LAP130\MSSQLSERVER1;Database=Sample 1;Uid=Meera;Password=meeraagrawal"`